How to Edit a "Primary Key" within the userform vs editing in the worksheet?
My userform form is for managing orders. Each order is assigned a unique Shop Order Number that acts as a Primary Key.
For service orders, I need to create a temporary Shop Order Number, for example: TSO-10000-SO-01 ("01" is the temporary placeholder for the sales order number yet to be created).
Once the service is completed, I generate a sales order number. I then have to change the temporary Shop Order Number to the permanent number. In this example: TSO-10000-SO-01 changes to TSO-10000-SO-623453.
Currently, I have to go to the worksheet to make the edit. Instead, I would like to be able to edit this from the userform.
The challenge is that I use the Shop Order Number like a Primary Key. How do I edit a Primary Key without compromising the matching row? Here is the code I use to save the userform data to the worksheet.
I'm a new with VBA and appreciate your help.
Private Sub cmbSave_Click()
'redacted code here....
    
    'Saves the order
    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Dim orderTable As ListObject                  'Best option for reading/writing to a worksheet with a table
    Dim son    As String
    Dim matchRow As Variant
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("MASTER")
    Set orderTable = Worksheets("Master").ListObjects("tblMASTER")
    
    son = Trim(txtShopOrdNum)
    matchRow = Application.Match(son, orderTable.ListColumns("SHOP ORDER NUMBER").DataBodyRange, 0)
    If Not IsError(matchRow) Then
        With orderTable.ListRows(matchRow)
            .Range(1, 1).Value = txtPrefix
            .Range(1, 2).Value = cboOrderType
            .Range(1, 3).Value = cboStatus
            .Range(1, 4).Value = txtSuffix
            .Range(1, 5).Value = txtShopOrdNum
            .Range(1, 6).Value = txtEmailSubLine
'redacted code for columns 7-120 here...
            .Range(1, 121).Value = txtEUNickname
            .Range(1, 122).Value = txtEUID
            .Range(1, 123).Value = Date & " " & Time 'Timestamp
        End With
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
'redacted code here...  
    
End Sub


Is "SHOP ORDER NUMBER" column #5 in your table?  Is son the temporary or the final key?   It's not that clear to me exactly what the problem is here.  Do you use the same temporary key for all non-complete records?  Why not assign a unique key in the first place, so you don't have to change it later - it shouldn't matter if a record never graduates to a completed state.

If this is saving a record previously loaded from the worksheet, store the row you loaded it from, so you can update the key on the sheet without needing to find it again...

Hi Tim! Yes, the SHOP ORDER NUMBER is in Col5. son represents all SHOP ORDER NUMBERS permanent or temporary.
I do not use the same temporary key for all non-complete records. I agree with you on assigning a unique key in the first place, but I've adopted this process when I was hired. I'm trying to manage it in the short term, while I attempt to implement unique keys for Service in the long term. I was hoping I could find a temporary solution while I campaign for change.

Also, I don't understand your second comment - "store the row you loaded it from, so you can update the key..." Thx!

If you use the userform to edit an existing row which has a temporary id and you want to update the id as part of the edit, you can't then use the updated id to find the row to update on the worksheet.  So when you load the row to edit it, store the source row number so you can return the edited record to the sheet without needing to match on id.

...or (#2) save the original id from the worksheet row in a varaible, and use that to locate the row to be updated with a new id from txtShopOrdNum
